# How to install QGIS 2.6 with GRASS functions?

Tags: grass-gis, error, qgis-2.6, function

I install QGIS 2.6 but QGIS-OSGeo4w didn't install GRASS functions. I removed other versions from control panel (feature and program) but, in all of times that I install it, I confront with this error when I open it:

> QGIS couldn't find your GRASS installation. Would you like to specify
>   path (GISBASE) to your GRASS installation?

I choose all of folders but all of efforts was unsuccessful.

Comment: @xunilk thank you but I want to install QSWAT I force to use 2.6 version, can I install GRASS and QGIS separately my dear friend?

Comment: I only edited your question but answer is yes. You do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to install QGIS and GRASS is with the OSGeo4W Setup. Choose the "Advanced". Then when you get to the "Select Packages" window, go to Libs and choose qgis-grass-plugin-common and qgis-grass-plugin7. In Desktop, choose grass.

I would install 2.18.10 instead of 2.6 though... And delete any previous version using the same method you used to install it.

Comment: thanks my friend but I need to install  2.6 because I want to use QSWAT and it's compatible just with this version. Which of the version of GRASS Is compatible with version of 2.6?

Comment: Any GRASS GIS 7.x version should be fine.

Comment: @Gob Tron thank you but these packages libs are for 2.18 not for 2.6 ,I need to install 2.6 version. Which libs should be active?

Comment: You marked my answer as "Best answer". I was wondering then, did you install grass plugins for 2.18 on you 2.6 QGIS?